# At(@) symbol in cloudant lucene search

Tags: cloudant

If i use At(@) symbol in regular expression based search as explained here http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description the lucene search treats it as 'any string' and doesn't match the character '@' .. Even escaping with backslash is not working. I'm using cloudant java client.

Is there is a way to use '@' in regular expression search of cloudant lucene search?

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you are using keyword analyzer for that indexed field. But you have to see whether keyword analyzer is the right one for your requirements.

```
"Data":"TestMe@"    
{"q":"Data:/TestMe[@]/"}
```